# User Selected Columns of 2D Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a `C++` program, that will take the user defined number of columns at run time and create a two dimensional array that will have

**Columns = given at run time

Rows = 3<sup>Columns</sup>**

How should I initialize a 2D array where the rows and columns are not initially constants. Any link or tutorial help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Windows ?

Comment: Are you using visual c++ on visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for dynamic multi-dimensional arrays. Googlefu should help, leads to this article:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/63/

Look near the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You provided us a little information, I guess you are asking for a C++ code that first takes column number from user and then calculates rows on the basis of formula and finally creates a two dimensional array, right ?

 Formula given : **rows = 3<sup>columns</sup>**.

I've written a C++ code for you

I've tested this code on my linux( ubuntu ) platform , I hope this is what you are asking.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>
#define kary 3 // Your k-ary truth table - 3 for ternary truth table(0,1,2), 2 for binary truth table(1,2)

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int rows,cols,i,j;  // Variable declaration
    cout<<"\n Enter required number of columns =  ";
    cin>>cols;
    rows = pow(kary,cols);
    cout<<"\n Calculated number of rows =  "<<rows;
    int arr[rows][cols]; // Array declaration
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<cols; j++)
           arr[i][j]=((i/(int) pow(kary, j)) % kary); //logic
    }
    cout<<"\n Your array holds this data \n";
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j=cols-1; j>=0; j--)
            cout<<"\t"<<arr[i][j];
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vegetarian Vulture! However, the: "int arr[rows][cols];" brings several errors including C2057: expected constant expression, C2133: 'arr':unknown size, and C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0. Any idea around that? That is what I was getting before.

Comment: When I try to run your code, those ^^ are the errors that I get. It works fine for you?

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you for your help Deepak. I am using Visual Studio. What happened with POW is I needed to declare it a double and not int. However, still having problems with declaring the array.

Comment: Nvm I figured that part out.

Comment: I was able to get it to initialize, but now having trouble with the radix math

Comment: I am using MS Visual Studio for C++

Comment: The number of columns will be user selected.
The number of rows equals 3^(columns) <--exponent not XOR 
- This is because each column has the possibility of having the numbers 0,1,or 2

For example, if the user were to select "4" columns, then the array would have 4 columns and 3^4=81 rows. 

Then I would like to populate this with all of the possible combinations of 0,1,2
i.e.
0000
0001
0002
0010
0011
0012
0020
0021
0022
0100
....
2220
2221
2222

Any idea how I would create the "For" Loop for this?

Comment: Due to my very busy schedule I wasn't able to answer your question but I've updated my answer now.... and now this completely fulfills your request, additionally I've created a variable which can be used to change base of your truth table, which is 3 in your case(0-1-2). This is what you wanted to do.... Please accept/vote up if you think the answer worth it...!!